# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 'Not authorized to open root of edit operation'

Tags: svn, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, mod-dav-svn

After migration from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS To Ubuntu 14.04 LTS my Apache SVN (mod dav_svn) behavior changed.

I began getting **Not authorized to open root of edit operation** when updating from the server on projects already checked out.

I have multiple repos with independent AuthzSVNAccessFile files, with some sharing the same AuthUserFile file.

Previously, on 12.04 LTS, all requests from a browser to the root of a repo (e.g. /Example1) would prompt the user to login.

I have seen suggestions have been to add `* = r` in the AuthzSVNAccessFile, which is not an option, as all users must be logged in, ie all repos required authentication.

**I am looking to fix the 'Not authorized to open root of edit operation' error message on update.**

### Details

Example entries in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf`:

```
...
<Location /Example1>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /home/svn/Example1

    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/subversion/svnauthz-Example1.conf

    Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/svn-passwords
</Location>


<Location /Example2>

  DAV svn
  SVNPath /home/svn/Example2

  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/subversion/svnauthz-Example2.conf

  Satisfy Any
  Require valid-user

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/svn-passwords

</Location>
...
```

Example AuthzSVNAccessFile:

```
[/]
juser = rw
```

Application versions:

```
$  apt-show-versions apache2
apache2:i386/trusty-security 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1 uptodate

$ apt-show-versions libapache2-svn
libapache2-svn:all/trusty-security 1.8.8-1ubuntu3.1 uptodate
```

Clients:

```
Versions v1.3.0 on OSX
svn command line v1.7.10 (r1485443) on OSX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My error was to use `Satisfy Any` instead of `Satisfy All`.

Not sure why things worked with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 'caught' or brought my error to light.

Comment: There's probably an `Allow from all` somewhere in your config and the `Satisfy any` means that is enough to allow the request without requesting authentication.  The difference is probably with the default configuration of Apache that is included with Ubuntu 14.04 as opposed to the difference in Apache versions between Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04.